# Is there a way i can restyle form items on iphone?

Tags: css

I'm working on making my site responsive and i have a form on my site.
I restyled my form using css, but on iphone the styles "gone lost" and they have default styles of iphone.

Is there any way i can style them ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are searching this:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Or for other Browsers:

```
 Safari  --webkit-appearance

 Mozilla --moz-appearance
```

Comment: I tried it on my iPhone: Take the button: <input type="submit" value="Submit"> without any CSS Value. Safari change your button in a Safari like Button. If you change the CSS Value to: -webkit-appearance: none; Safari delete the style and you can formate the button yourself.